# Can't convert a RAW SD card(MBR formatted) to NTFS or any other windows readable file system

Tags: partitioning, ntfs, formatting, sd-card, diskpart

I want to convert my RAW sd card to NTFS or FAT32 file system. I tried using `diskpart` and tons of other third party tools to recover it but my sd card is partitioned MBR style and I believe `diskpart` can't convert MBR partitoned RAW sd card to NTFS. So can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Could you define raw?

Comment: Why are you trying to convert it? Why not just format it? if it is resisting all attempts to do anything with it, consider it dead & throw it away.